# How to read account data in non owner program

Tags: anchor, account

If I deploy a program `P1` which initialises a new account `A1` and update the `rvalue` to for instance 9

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    rvalue: u64
}
```

Now if we deploy Program `P2` and want to read the `rvalue` as 9 which is saved in `A1`. Any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: Can I get the repo link? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem, all accounts are readable by programs, regardless of who owns them. You just need access to the `NewAccount` structure on `P2` so Anchor knows how to deserialise it.

To do this, you can import `P1` using the `no-entrypoint` feature on your `Cargo.toml`. With that flag, you can access everything on `P1` as a library instead of a standalone program.

The `Cargo.toml` would look something like:

```
...

[dependencies.P1]
path = "../programs/P1"
features = ["no-entrypoint"]
```

Once you have imported `P1` on `P2`, it's as easy as creating a new instruction context and providing the account you initialised as one of the accounts of the instruction.

```
use P1::state::NewAccount;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UseNewAccount<'info> {
 
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,

    ...

}
```

And then, on the function that handles the instruction, you'll be able to use `ctx.accounts.new_account.rvalue` which will give you 9.

I think I'm not missing anything, let me know otherwise :)

**Edit 01**: The explanation above has turned into a complete example on [this github repository](https://github.com/nf0x/deserialise-pda-from-a-different-program) .

Comment: So on solana devnet i deployed program at 721WuW2yfmZvyAVJu4hY4tjELtUNq6CLbM4HUhGSKGQ4 and used it to init a new_account at 8P98zdUzy78TReciQ17C3spiYrRN2vWb2zy6JSnGom9D

Now I've deployed a program at D9FmsxUEsDRZyMffypMeLVTPoSax7JQ5jjp3nrVNKWzQ 

But I am unable to fetch the data. It keeps saying `The given account is not owned by the executing program`

Comment: Have you perhaps marked `new_account` as `#[account(mut)]` (making it mutable) on `P2`? I haven't tried but I assume you can't mutate an account you don't own and that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: I actually did not mark it as `#[account(mut)]`.
Would love if someone can try the above mentioned solution so that I can check if only I am facing this problem

Comment: There you go, this worked on my end: https://github.com/nf0x/deserialise-pda-from-a-different-program. If you compile it, change the program ids to the ones on your `target`, and run `anchor test`, the tests should pass. Note that there are hardcoded program ids on `tests/T.ts`, change those too :)